# Rewrite so sub domain works when www. in typed in front

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, no-www

I know this is fairly straightforward rewrite but I can not get it working and have searched for similar question.

I have created several sub domains for my client.  However, many visitors are still typing `www.` in front of sub domain.  I need rewrite to remove `www.` before any sub domains.

For example:
I have  `subdomain.mydomain.com`
If someone enters: `www.subdomain.mydomain.com`
I need to go to: `subdomain.mydomain.com`

Thank You in Advance
Chip

Answer (score 0):

This can work in your vhosts configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com$1 [R,L]
```

Then some command like this to restart apache2:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

.

Comment: doesn't seem to work unless other Rewrites in the file are conflicting RewriteEngine On is already on so I didn't included
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bret\.lakerealty\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bret.lakerealty.com$1 [R,L]

Comment: It's strange, I've tested this redirect in vhosts: http ://www.subdomain.example.com/monstrer => http ://subdomain.example.com/monster works with apache2.

RedirectEngine On can be repeated many times.